# Android layout circle centered

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to do a circular menu out of imageButtons that will be centered in the view. So the layout is full screen (forced to landscape) and my circle is composed of 4 quarters of a circle. I want a layout that will bring the 4 quarters (quadrants) of the circle, together in the center of the page.
Is that possible?
I mean, I did some work on a layout that looks relatively good at design time, as you can see in the picture bellow:
[image: Deigntime]
, but at runtime (emulator), the 4 quadrants are split like you can see in the image:
[image]

What can I do to solve this?
Here is my code for the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img_actualizare"
                android:src="@drawable/left_top"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img_vizitare"
                android:src="@drawable/right_top"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="190dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img_clienti"
                android:src="@drawable/left_bottom"
                android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                android:cropToPadding="false"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false" />
        </RelativeLayout>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/img_notificari"
                android:src="@drawable/right_bottom" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you setting this layout to activity? or including to other layout?

Comment: I want this layout in an activity. It would act like a main menu

Comment: I don't see any issue with the layout. try to test in a device

Comment: I don't have a device to test it on, and anyway as far as I understood layouts behave differently on different devices so I am trying to achieve an independent solution that does not look different on different screens... Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

try to set the scaletype of the ImageViews to scaleXY.

[ImageView.ScaleType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

Comment: No change. Please try the layout in your IDE and see for yourself